# How can I control three different threads using threading in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, variables, global, python-multithreading

I have thread1, thread2 and thread3, global variable `x` and three different functions to increment `x`,

```
import threading
import time

#check = threading.Condition()
x=1

def add_by1():
    global x
    x+=1
    time.sleep(1)
    print(x)
    

def add_by2():
    x+=2
    time.sleep(1)
    print(x)

def add_by3():
    x+=3
    time.sleep(1)
    print(x)

if __name__==__main__:
    threading.Thread(target=add_by1).start()
    threading.Thread(target=add_by2).start()
    threading.Thread(target=add_by3).start()

# I want the output should print.. 
"""
2
4
7
8
10
13
14
16
19
and so on ..
"""
```

can I use the `Condition()`, if so how? can I use other threading classes?, how would I insert some  codes on these functions?

Comment: What do you want to use `threading.Condition` for? Did you read about [what a Condition does](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#condition-objects) in a multithreading environment?

Comment: Im just thinking maybe it would solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this approach is reliable. You can synchronize your threads using three `lock` objects - one for each.

The way this setup works is each thread acquires *its* lock and after doing its job, it releases next thread's lock! IOW, `add_by1` releases `thread_lock_two`, `add_by2` releases `thread_lock_three` and lastly `add_by3` releases `thread_lock_one`.

Initially you need to acquire `thread_lock_two` and `thread_lock_three`'s lock so that only the first thread does its job.

Whenever the condition is met (you said `x == 20`), each thread should again release next thread's lock **also** `return` !

```py
import threading
from time import sleep

x = 1

thread_lock_one = threading.Lock()
thread_lock_two = threading.Lock()
thread_lock_three = threading.Lock()

thread_lock_two.acquire()
thread_lock_three.acquire()


def add_by1():
    global x
    while True:
        thread_lock_one.acquire()
        if x >= 20:
            thread_lock_two.release()
            return
        x += 1
        print(x)
        sleep(0.6)
        thread_lock_two.release()


def add_by2():
    global x
    while True:
        thread_lock_two.acquire()
        if x >= 20:
            thread_lock_three.release()
            return
        x += 2
        print(x)
        sleep(0.6)
        thread_lock_three.release()


def add_by3():
    global x
    while True:
        thread_lock_three.acquire()
        if x >= 20:
            thread_lock_one.release()
            return
        x += 3
        print(x)
        sleep(0.6)
        thread_lock_one.release()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    threading.Thread(target=add_by1).start()
    threading.Thread(target=add_by2).start()
    threading.Thread(target=add_by3).start()
```

output:

```
2
4
7
8
10
13
14
16
19
20
```

Comment: how could I kill the threads then? can I do quit() when certain value of x is met?

Comment: @fardV I re-wrote the answer using another approach. This way threads are killed when the condition is met or for example `x` reaches to 20.

Comment: very creative and amazing!! many thanks for solving this problem!!